# User Interface: Particle System

Tags: interface

I am try to learn Blender with understanding instead of memorizing, so the  question I have is as follows:

What is the reason of having the option to differently name the particle system in three steps: First in the modifier panel, second name for the particle system slot and third name for the particle itself?[image]

Comment: Blender has a structure to store all data in Datablocks. Some datablocks have references to others, so you can reuse the same datablock in multiple places. And this also happens with particles_systems. Objects refers to Modifiers(1), that refer to Particle_Systems(2), that refer to Particle_Settings(3). You can see this structure in the Outliner by choosing the DataAPI view.